# description of an ideal generated by the projections in a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^*$ algebra,$P_i$ are projections in $A$,$I$ is the ideal generated by the projections.I think $I$ is the $C^*$ algebra generated by $P_iAP_i$.How to charectarize $I$,is there a precise description of $I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the C$^*$-algebra generated by $P_iAP_i$. For instance take $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, $P=E_{11}$. The ideal generated by $P$ is $A$, and not $PAP=\mathbb C P$.

The ideal generated by elements $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ in $A$ is the C$^*$-subalgebra generated by $$\{ ax_jb:\ a,b\in A,\ j=1,\ldots,m\}.$$ I don't think you can get anything specific here. Unless the projections are central; in the case the ideal would be $P_1A+\cdots+P_mA$.

Comment: If the ideal $I$ generated by  a infinite set $S$,is  ideal $I$ the $C^*$ subalgebra generated by $\{ axb:\ a,b\in A,\ x\in S\}$?

Comment: Yes, it's actually the closed linear span of that set.

Comment: Pro Argerami,I have another question:If $A$ is nonunital,I think  the ideal $I$ does not contain $S$ since any $a,b\in A$ cannot be $1_{A}$.Is it correct?

Comment: No, you cannot say that in general. In $c_0$, the ideal generated by $x=(1/n)_n$ does not contain $x$ (because $x=yx$ cannot be satisfied by any $y\in c_0$); but the ideal generated by $e_1$ is $\mathbb C e_1$, which contains $e_1$.

Comment: Quick question: Is it really the usual convention that an element is not necessarily in the ideal it generates? That seems very odd! Do you have a comment on why this is the convention?

Comment: You are right that there is an ambiguity. If you think in terms of "the smallest ideal that contains it" then you are right.